# C++ Heap profiler for Android

Tags: android, c++, memory, java-native-interface, valgrind

I have some lengthy C++ JNI Code where I want to test memory leaks.
I have tried the following for profiling heap memory:

1. **[Malloc Debug](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/libc/malloc_debug/README.md)**: This made the app so slow that it never opens.
2. **Valgrind**: This is giving "Unsupported clone() flags:" error and quitting.
3. **Address Sanitizer**: For some weird reason, Leak Sanitizer is still not supported on Android.
4. The **Android Profiler** on Android Studio seems to be good for Java heap and not JNI heap. Although it can show Native Heap usage, it cannot show the back-trace of heap allocation in case of leaks.

What do people use nowadays for heap profiling C++ code on Android ? Is there any other good tool that I am missing ?

Comment: Google I/O 2019 suggested to use Address Sanitizer which can detect corruption only not leaks. malloc_debug for leaks.. Anything you found to address malloc Debug slowness? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9GF_X-cq3E

Comment: Last time I checked NDK Address Sanitizer does not include Leak Sanitizer